# Bit twiddling: interleave bytes in word with zero bytes using bitwise operators (<<, |, &, etc)

Tags: java, performance, assembly, bit-manipulation

Given a `long` with bytes `WXYZ` (where each letter is a byte), I would like some fast bit twiddling code that will create two `longs` with the same bytes as the original, but interleaved with the 0 byte.

For example, given the `long` with value `ABCDEFGH` (each letter being one byte), produce the two longs:

```
0A0B0C0D
0E0F0G0H
```

Something equivalent to, but faster than:

```
long result1 = expand((int)(input >>> 32));
long result2 = expand((int)input);

long expand(int inputInt) {
  long input = intputInt;
  return
    (input & 0x000000FF)       | 
    (input & 0x0000FF00) <<  8 | 
    (input & 0x00FF0000) << 16 | 
    (input & 0xFF000000) << 24;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any statistics for the speed of your proposed implementation? Also, do you have any reason to believe that it's possible to do it any faster?

Comment: Please pick a language/technology.  Not doing so makes this not constructive/not a real question.

Comment: Your implementation is not right.  You need to be shifting by 8, 16, 24, and 32 in order to obtain the results you seem to be indicating you want.

Comment: Look for SSE vector conversions, for example: https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/ve/sse.html#Translation_Conv_I2I_S2L of small integer vector into large one. You may not be able to access the high-performance CPU features thru Java though.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - you are right, I've corrected my implementation.

Comment: @casperOne - I'm pretty much picking C, Java and C++ because they all provide the same basic bit shifting operations. If you have a solution that works in one of those languages, I'm happy to see because it's very likely it will work in the others which offer nearly identical operators.

Comment: @Code-Guru - I don't have specific evidence (the most specific evidence would be a better implementation, in which case I would have posted it).  My experience with bit-twiddling, however, is that remarkable things can be accomplished in many cases, increasing speed considerably.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much exactly what I want.  Not available in a cross platform way in high level languages, unfortunately.

Comment: which is why, if you want high performance code, you have to separate small high-calling-frequency parts away into libraries loaded under conditionals of architecture. Intel Compiler can do it automatically for you.

Comment: @Code-Guru - I'm using the method to expand an array of longs into an array of 2x as many longs, interleaved in the way described.

The given implementation takes 12 ns per element on a 2.53 Mhz Core i3, in Java.  So that's ~30 cycles, but the method is called twice (once for each of the 2 longs generated), so about 15 cycles per element.

Comment: When you choose a technology, this can be reopened.  The voting system isn't really suited for apples-and-oranges (or gorillia vs. shark if you will) comparisons, which is the situation that the multiple language tags pose.

Comment: Are you kidding? I've explicitly laid out the technology:

Languages with the usual bit shifting operators.  All of the code above and in the suggested answers works verbatim in all of those languages.

Given that the question is specific and there is already one answer which represents a significant improvement, I fail to see how this isn't constructive.

Should I open three separate questions with each language tag? Doesn't seem to make any sense, but would somehow get around the "one language tag per question" rule I never heard of, I guess?

Comment: Seems a perfectly constructive question to me. This question is not even about "language comparison". There is no rule on SO that questions should be limited to one language, especially in cases where there are obvious similarities and the same answer could be valid (as is the case in this one). Mods please re-open.

Comment: I removed the C and C++ tags.  Although your solution would work well there, I guess I have to play by the (obscure and undocumented) rule of no multi-language tags.  I took the chance to refine the question a bit - I'm doing this expansion to go from a long to two longs - I assumed doing the same thing to the high and low bits of the long is fastest, but perhaps there is some way this can be combined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is about 25% faster for me (Java 7, benchmarked using Google Caliper), YMMV may vary according to your compiler of course:

```
long a = (input | (input << 16));
long result = (a & 0xFF000000FFL) + ((a & 0xFF000000FF00L) <<8);
```

The idea is to use a bit of extra parallelism vs. the original approach.

The first line is a neat trick that produces garbage in bits 17-32, but you don't care as you are going to mask it out anyway. :-)

Comment: Exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I was hunting around for that divide and conquer approach to the shifts, but hadn't found how to avoid the garbage messing it up...

Comment: The first statement could be `long a = input * 0x10001;`. Then it is one operation (multiply) instead of two (shift, or). This will be faster on some machines (but not if the processor has a combined shift and insert-bit-field, and the compiler uses it).

Comment: Accepting this for now as the question has been closed, so new answers won't be incoming.  Will try out the * variant - thanks @EricPostpischil

Comment: Good suggestion @Eric. Just benchmarked and my machine it doesn't make any difference, but I agree it may be faster on some.

Answer (score 0):

```
long expand(int inputInt) {
  long input = intputInt;
  return
    (input & 0x000000FF) <<  8 | 
    (input & 0x0000FF00) << 16 | 
    (input & 0x00FF0000) << 24 | 
    (input & 0xFF000000) << 32;
}
```

Comment: Um, yeah, that's  my example implementation, but I'm looking for something faster.  Note I changed the spec slightly - the 0s end up in the odd byte positions, not the even ones.  See the revised implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you could try to use a union:

```
typedef union
{
    char bytes[8];
    long value;
} PlatformSpecificSolution;

long expand(int valueInt)
{
    PlatformSpecificSolution pss;
    pss.value = valueInt;
    pss.bytes[6] = pss.bytes[3]; pss.bytes[3] = 0;
    pss.bytes[4] = pss.bytes[2]; pss.bytes[2] = 0;
    pss.bytes[2] = pss.bytes[1]; pss.bytes[1] = 0;
    // pss.bytes[0] = pss.bytes[0];
    return pss.value;
 }
```

I have no idea if this is faster (you will have to run benchmarks on the platforms that you want to support). This solution is definitely more error prone. You should always ask yourself, if the performance benefit outways the disadvantage of less maintainable code.

Comment: Intesting approach, I'm trying this out on a couple platforms.  It looks like the total number of operations is comparable, but there is a lot inherent parallelism here at the processor may be able to exploit.  OTOH, many of the instructions are probably memory access (which will hit L1, granted) rather than register to register ones.

Comment: You could conceivably combine this with loop unrolling